# How to typeset special Apple Mac keyboard symbols?

Tags: symbols, packages, mac

Is there a standard way to typeset the special symbols of the Apple Mac keyboard? That is, the curly rectangle ⌘ and the others?

If there is none, what would you suggest as workarounds?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is the Apple Keys package available here: [Apple Keys](https://herbs.github.io/).

It has character sized images for the following symbols:

[image: list of keys]

Comment: Thanks. I’ve found this Package to but only with an old broken download link.

Comment: @Tobi That's the problem with people not putting things on CTAN. I've tried to convince Herb Schulz to do this, but he thinks it's not worth it.

Comment: Bummer! (Does that mean the same as “What a pity“?dic.leo.org, said that …)

Comment: @Tobi Yes, that's a pretty good definition of it. (Although you can also say "What a bummer." ) :-).

Comment: Thanks: I thought that “what a pity” sounds to *cute* like talking to a baby/ little child … These are the important things they don’t teach at school :-/

Comment: Where should the `.eps` and `.pdf` files go in the (local) texmf tree?

Comment: @murray Just put the whole `applekeys` folder into `<path-to-local-texmf/tex/latex` The graphics don't need to be in a separate place.

Comment: @Alan Munn: OK, that works. Of course I was going to put the `.sty` file in `<path-to-local-texmf>/tex/latex`; I was just uncertain about the graphics files. I'd suggest a little readme file saying that.

Answer (score 30):

A few month ago I released [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) an now an upvote remind me of this question, so I’d like to announce the package here. It contains symbols for (I hope) all Apple and Windows Keys.

[image: symbols]

The symbols are produced with TikZ. The code can be found in `menukeys.sty` or in the implementation section of the manual.

Furthermore the package offers macros to typeset shortcuts.

[image: example]

```
To set the unit of the rulers go to \menu{Extras > Settings > Rulers}
and choose between millimetres, inches and pixels. The short cut to
view the rulers is \keys{cmd + R}. Pressing these keys again will
hide the rulers.

The standard path for saving your document is \directory{Macintosh HD/
Users/ Your Name/Documents} but you can change it at \menu{Extras >
Settings > Saving} by clicking \menu{Change save path}.
```

Comment: Nice package, but comparing with Herb's package, the Mac escape and delete keys look reversed, and you are missing a couple of keys (control, eject.)  Oddly enough, the newer Macs no longer have the funny Option symbol.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Hi Alan, sorry for the late reply, I added you comment to may to do list and I’ll look at it when I got some more time :-)

Comment: @AlanMunn: I finally updated `menukeys` and fixed the esc symbol :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can use some of the symbols directly.

However, be aware that only few fonts actually contain all symbols, so you might have to load it from a different font (like XITS, DejaVu Sans or FreeSerif):

```
% Compile with xelatex or lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\xits{xits.otf}

% provide a command for the command key symbol
\newcommand\cmdkey{{\xits ⌘}}
% make the symbol usable directly
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{⌘}{\cmdkey}

\begin{document}
Press the \cmdkey~key.
Release the ⌘ key.
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

For the record, common keys are

- ⌘ U+2318 place of interest sign
- ⌥ U+2325 option key
- ⌫ U+232B ERASE TO THE LEFT
- ⇧ U+21E7 UPWARDS WHITE ARROW
- ⌤ U+2324 UP ARROWHEAD BETWEEN TWO HORIZONTAL BARS
- ⇪ U+21EA upwards white arrow from bar
- ↵ U+21B5 DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS
- ↹ U+21B9 LEFTWARDS ARROW TO BAR OVER RIGHTWARDS ARROW TO BAR
- ⇥ U+21E5 RIGHTWARDS ARROW TO BAR
- ⏏ U+23CF EJECT SYMBOL
- ⎋ U+238B BROKEN CIRCLE WITH NORTHWEST ARROW

Answer (score 8):

Google found [AppleSymbols](https://web.archive.org/web/20110821012949/http://lindsay.at/files/tex/AppleSymbols.pdf) ([via](http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/apple-symbol-in-TeXLive-td637748.html)). Maybe this helps.

Alternatively you could draw them with TikZ. For the Apple-Logo I can give you a commans which includes an Image.

If you don’t like AppleSymbols I can help you with TikZ!

Comment: Seems like this is more extensive, but the other one solved my issue quicker. Thanks for the TikZ offer! I guess this would be nice to have TikZ snippets of the Apple's symbols - could produce nice results as well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Dror: I think that Alan’s answer is the better one, too. Did I understand you right, that you (at the moment) don’t need the TikZ symbols?

Comment: Yep - Alan's solution is the trick for me. I just said that it would be nice... :)

Comment: @Dror: OK … :-D

Comment: I didn't suggest that you should do it! Just as a general remark. Actually, a gallery with code snippets of common symbols could be really helpful.