# Create boxes to indicate keyboard keys

Tags: formatting, boxes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)

How would I create boxes around keyboard keys, similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?
I'm using TexMaker on Windows, but have got Linux (Ubuntu) based alternatives available, and need it for program documentation.  e.g. `keyboard short cuts based upon common standards (i.e. Ctrl + S to save data).`

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19646/how-to-typeset-the-special-macs-keyboards-symbols and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex