# Simple xelatex or latex document which contains an apple command character

Tags: xetex, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to typeset the special mac's keyboard's symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19646/how-to-typeset-the-special-macs-keyboards-symbols)

I don't know how to get an apple command sign in a latex or xetex document.
I know that this has been answered before, but the links to "apple keys"
package which is NO LONGER available. I have spent hours trying to figure
this out (and to find a nice introduction to xetex, which I have not yet found).

Please let me know.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}

  \setmainfont
  [  Extension = .otf,
   UprightFont = *-regular,
      BoldFont = *-bold,
    ItalicFont = *-italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-bolditalic,
  ]{xits}

  \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}

  % provide a command for the command key symbol
  \newcommand\cmdkey{{‚åò}}
  % make the symbol usable directly
  \usepackage{newunicodechar}
  \newunicodechar{‚åò}{\cmdkey}

  \begin{document}
  Press the \cmdkey~key.
  Release the ‚åò key.
  \end{document}

Comment: I moved my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19646/how-to-typeset-the-special-macs-keyboards-symbols. Also Alan updated the link to the package there.