# Where can I find on/off symbol?

Tags: symbols

Where do I find the on/off symbol of electronics?[image]

Comment: Check here http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: Also see [How to typeset special Apple Mac keyboard symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19646/5764); [`applekeys`](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10932738/Files/AppleKeys.zip) provides `\power` which is similar.

Comment: Is it really still appropriate to always link to http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/ ? The document is outdated by five years. Nowadays, with unicode, fontspec, and also TikZ we have more options than looking it up there and loading packages.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: This question is about half an years old and there are 4 good answers, please accept one of them!!!

Answer (score 17):

The package [`fontawesome`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) provides a lot of useful symbols:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faOff
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The `fontawesome` package contains a `\faoff` or `\faicon{off}` command for this. It is an OpenType font, so that you need `fontspec` and xelatex or lualatex to use it. Maybe `otftotfm` and `cfftot1`, from the LCDF type tools, might allow to obtain a type 1 version usable with (pdf)latex.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1,linecap=1](6,6)
    \psarc(3,3){2.5}{125}{55}
    \psline(3,3)(3,5.5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and short!

Comment: line cap of the arc must be round too. ;)

Comment: @percusse: It is not sharp anymore and becomes safe for children.

Answer (score 11):

And a `tikz` solution that can also be used as standalone symbol graphics:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\unit
\setlength{\unit}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=\unit,
  y=\unit,
  radius=\unit,
  line width=.4\unit,
  line cap=round,
]
  \draw[overlay]
    (0,1.2) -- (0,0)
    (130:1) [overlay] arc[start angle=130, delta angle=280]
  ;
  \path[use as bounding box] (-1.2,-1.2) (1.2,1.4);
  % arc is is taking the points of the internally used Bézier
  % curves into account for the bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The bounding box is specified separately, because `arc` uses the
  points of the internally used Bézier curve for the bounding box.
- I have used rounded line caps, they look better for my taste.

Answer (score 10):

You can drawing it yourself using PSTricks.

With 'sharp' corners:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand*\OnOff[1]{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,6.5)
 \psset{
   dimen = middel,
   linecolor = #1,
   fillstyle = solid,
   fillcolor = #1
 }
  \psRing(3,3)[125,55]{2}{3}
  \psarc(3,3){0.5}{180}{360}
  \psframe(2.5,3)(3.5,6)
  \psarcn(3,6){0.5}{180}{0}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \OnOff{black}
  \OnOff{blue}
  \OnOff{red}
  \OnOff{yellow}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

With 'round' corners:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand*\OnOff[1]{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,6.5)
 \psset{
   dimen = middel,
   linecolor = #1,
   fillstyle = solid,
   fillcolor = #1
 }
  \psarc(!3 2.5 130 cos mul add 3 2.5 130 sin mul add){0.5}{310}{130}
  \psRing(3,3)[130,50]{2}{3}
  \psarc(!3 2.5  50 cos mul add 3 2.5  50 sin mul add){0.5}{50}{230}
  \psarc(3,3){0.5}{180}{360}
  \psframe(2.5,3)(3.5,6)
  \psarcn(3,6){0.5}{180}{0}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \OnOff{black}
  \OnOff{blue}
  \OnOff{red}
  \OnOff{yellow}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]