# How can I insert the Apple Symbol ?

Tags: mac, input-encodings

For my thesis, I want to mention that Apple Pay is often stylized as ` Pay`, but the compiler warns me that this is an unknown character. It outputs `Ô£ø`. I have found that this symbol is encoded as `\uF8FF`.

How can I put this so that it outputs the apple symbol?

Comment: You need to find a font that has that character defined.  It is possible to use one of the Apple system fonts if you are using either Xetex or Luatex.

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{F8FF}{<whatever you want the symbol  to print>}`

Comment: Related (albeit old): [How to typeset special Apple Mac keyboard symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19646/4778)

Answer (score 3):

You need

1. a font -- likely an OpenType or TrueType font -- that features the Apple symbol and
2. a typesetting engine that can work with this font.

For the latter, both Xe(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX qualify. Examples of font families that feature the symbol are `Apple Chancery`, `Helvetica (Neue)`, and `Zapfino`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex    
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\apple}{\char"F8FF}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Apple Chancery} abc \apple{} def

\bigskip
\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue} abc \apple{} def

\bigskip
\setmainfont{Zapfino} abc \apple{} def
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to define a new command. Most fonts support the direct typing of .

Comment: @Alenanno - Umm, my keyboard doesn't have a key for , so how am I supposed to type it directly? And, speaking for myself, I find it much easier to type `\apple` than `\char"F8FF`. Separately, what do you mean by "most fonts" in this context? On my system, most fonts do *not* feature this symbol.

Comment: it depends if you have a Macintosh, but I can type it with the key combination Shift-Alt-8. It's faster for me, at least if you know the combination (but it's not a problem using the digital keyboard for reference). I opened a text file, added the  in it, and scrolled through some fonts and 99% of them had it. I didn't check all the fonts though so my perspective might be biased. :D

Comment: @Alenanno - Well, I happen to have a MacBookPro, and it doesn't have an "Alt" key. Thus, unfortunatey, I can't enter "Shift-Alt-8"...

Comment: Of course you can! :D The Alt key is also known as Option or ⌥.

Comment: @Alenanno - Unfortunately, "Shift-Option-8" in my text editor (TeXworks) produces a raised small circle, *not* the Apple symbol. I honestly don't get what you're driving at.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? It might change according to the language. I'm not driving anywhere, just saying that you should have it.

Comment: On an American or Canadian keyboard layout the apple symbol is option-shift-K.  On a German layout it's option-shift-+.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks. I indeed use the US keyboard layout. (I occasionally use the Swiss German keyboard layout; I just found out that for that layout, option-shift-- ("dash") generates .) That said, I find easier to type `\apple` than to have to remember whether the applicable key combination is option-shift-K, option-shift-"dash", or whatever else it may be for a given keyboard layout...

Comment: This did not solve my problem, as I don't use a compatible engine. The duplicate answer fixed my problem, but I didn't import the whole package, only the one command I needed for the .

Comment: i find it disconcerting that with zapfino, the apple symbol is obliqued.  seems like an overcompensation.